# Ordnance Survey Tile Tracking Solutions?

Tags: web-mapping, web-service, ordnance-survey

We want to find a way to track how and how many tiles are drawn in the Ordnance Survey API (or through a different way if that is easier). As you may know, the royalty charges are per tile so we want to see if there is a way to track how tiles are drawn in our app without writing a software solution. It may overall end up that we'll have to write one (considering how they want to be invoiced quarterly), but for budgeting and testing purposes if there is a quick / rudimentary way to do it before we get down to finer details, that is the solution I am looking for. So far I've been able to use the inspect tool in Chrome to view how many tiles get loaded in one view of our app but a scaleable solution is what I am looking for.

For reference, each tile is 256x256 regardless of scale (same as OSM so maybe a solution people use for OSM might work in this case). I was thinking of just doing some good ol' math to figure out how many tiles might fit within a predetermined boundary we could set up in our app, however that isn't very precise given that I don't know how many tiles might be loaded outside of the boundary, whether monitor resolution has anything to do with it etc.

Comment: A simple Google search threw up this [mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/interactive-tools/offline-estimator/) website.

Comment: look in the access log - a simple awk script should be able to sum up the requests